# How to bind two elements to single source in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

My scenario is that there are two controls. One in which you set up minutes and second in which you specify seconds.

Both of them should be bound to single property in view model. This property is of type string. This string is in format [hh:mm:ss]. So changing value in "minutes" control should change 'mm' portion of the string and changing the value in "seconds" control should change the 'ss' portion of the string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cleanest way I can think of is to just have two more properties on the VM, and in their setters adjust the final time string appropriately. Are you sure you can't add any more properties to the VM?

Comment: You could use two converters : one that take the source string and outputs mm and the other that outputs ss. But as mentioned above, have 2 properties is cleaner.

Comment: If you use converters, you will need to pass in the complete value as a parameter to the converter, so that you can reconstitute everything. But still, extra properties has to be the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 3-property ViewModel working solution if you are using `TimeSpan` and its range is between 0 and 59h 59s.  I have not fully tested and conditions/validation will change based on requirements. I used `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` because that's the resolution we needed; meaning, when setting the `TimeSpan` to a new value, we would just set the total number of seconds through the public property.  An alternative could be to have 2 `TimeSpan` properties in your ViewModel, then when setting the public property, you could call `_item.TotalSeconds = VMMinutes.TotalSeconds + VMSeconds.TotalSeconds.TotalSeconds`.  Basically you have many design options here.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Border Height="60" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Minutes"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Minutes}" />
                <Label Content="Seconds"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Seconds}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <Border Height="60" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Total Seconds"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TotalSeconds}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ItemViewModel(new Item(new TimeSpan(0, 3, 59)));
    }
}
```

**ItemViewModel.cs**:

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Item _item;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ItemViewModel(Item item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public string TotalSeconds
    {
        get
        {
            return _item.TotalSeconds.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            double newTotSecs;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                if(double.TryParse(value, out newTotSecs))
                {
                    _item.TotalSeconds = newTotSecs;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Minutes");
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Seconds");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public string Seconds
    {
        get
        {
            return (_item.TotalSeconds % 60).ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            int newVal;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                if(int.TryParse(value, out newVal))
                {
                    if(newVal >= 0 && newVal <= 59)
                    {
                        int totMinSec;
                        if(int.TryParse(Minutes, out totMinSec))
                        {
                            _item.TotalSeconds = (totMinSec * 60) + newVal;
                            NotifyPropertyChanged();
                            NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalSeconds");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public string Minutes
    {
        get
        {
            return ((int)(_item.TotalSeconds / 60)).ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            int newVal;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                if(int.TryParse(value, out newVal))
                {
                    if(newVal >= 0 && newVal <= 59)
                    {
                        int totSec;
                        if(int.TryParse(Seconds, out totSec))
                        {
                            _item.TotalSeconds = totSec + (newVal * 60);
                            NotifyPropertyChanged();
                            NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalSeconds");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Item.cs**:

```
public class Item
{
    private TimeSpan _time;
    public double TotalSeconds
    {
        get
        {
            return _time.TotalSeconds;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value >= 0)
            {
                _time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)value);
            }
        }
    }
    public Item(TimeSpan time)
    {
        _time = time;
    }
}
```

[image]

**Note:** Your other option is to use a `Converter`, which I haven't provided a solution for.  I think it could end up being cleaner in the long run since all you really need to pass to back and forth is the converter is total number of seconds.

Comment: Where is the sense in these nested if blocks? You know there are logical operators like `&&`?

Comment: Of course I do.  Illustrates logical steps being taken. If OP needs comments on whats going on, much easier to add them above the if-statement rather than comment on right side for each condition.  I'm sorry my styling isn't pleasing to you, but when half the community doesn't know truth tables/boolean algebra, its much easier to illustrate what you're doing by not combining everything possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would use NETScape's approach above, but encapsulate it in a user control. The user control XAML would be something like:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <TextBlock Text="Minutes" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding InternalMinutes}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

       <TextBlock Text="Seconds" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding InternalSeconds}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then in the code-behind, you would have a Dependency Property for the actual `DateTime` object, and properties to bind against (you could use a view model for this, or just go off of `TextChanged`. When its all View logic, its ok!).

An example property would be:

```
public int InternalSeconds
{
    get { return ExternalTime.Seconds; }
    set
    {
         ExternalTime.Seconds = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Again, there are multiple approaches here, you could use a converter in order to use an intermediate object. `ExternalTime` is the DP here, make sure to handle its `Changed` event if you expect the value to change outside of this control.